# Adjust for sprite anchor points after drag and drop

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am selecting a number of sprites with the following:

```
_nodeArray = [self nodesAtPoint:[_previousTouch locationInNode:self]];
```

I then create a container (SKNode) and add the _nodeArray as child's so i can move the container and it's children at the same time using UIPanGestureRecognizer. I also calculate the relative position vs. the container so they stay in position when i drop them.

If the sprites are located like this, not fully on top of each other:

[image]

...when I move the container (the group of sprites) and drop it the pack adjust and move to, what i think, the container anchorPoint (default). It does not move much but it doesn't look good. I guess the reason is that the container anchorPoint is not located in the middle of the pack of sprites, which is were the drag is.

I am not able to figure out how of adjust this, and if it is possible at all, and just wonder if anyone have any suggestions how to make the pack of sprites stay exactly were i drop it.